# Php code not working as expected

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple one user one password custom login to protect a specific page. In the page I want to protect (gallery.php) I have the following code:

```
<?php 

session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["Login"]){
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>

<p>some protected content</p>
```

As so if user enters url http://www.example.com/pics/gallery.php

the pages take you to       http://www.example.com/pics/index.php

In index I have the fallowing code:

```
<?php

session_start();
      if(($_POST['username'] == "user1") && ($_POST['pass'] == "pass1"))
  { 
    $_SESSION["Login"]= true;
    header("Location:gallery.php");
  }
 else
 { ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="wlcm">
    <div class="login-box wow fadeInUp">
        <h2 class="lgn-tle">Please login</h2>

        <form name="login" method="post" accept-charset='UTF-8'>

            <input 
                type="text" 
                id="username" 
                name="username" 
                class="wow fadeInUp" 
                data-wow-delay=".2s" 
                placeholder="User"
                required="true">

            <input 
                type="password" 
                id="pass"
                name="pass" 
                class="wow fadeInUp" 
                data-wow-delay=".4s" 
                placeholder="Password"
                required="true">

            <input 
                type="submit" 
                name="Submit"
                class="submit wow fadeInUp" 
                data-wow-delay=".6s" 
                value="Login">

        </form>


    </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        echo "incorrect";
      }
 }
?>
```

While the code on gallery.php works and takes user to login.php if he's not already logged in. When I submit correct info in index.php I just get a blank page without any php errors.

It seems like header("Location:gallery.php"); doesn't do anything and I have tried absolute paths and spaces after "Location".

Am I missing something here? 
All I want is a custom login using an html form instead of .htaccess and to do so in the simples and cleaner possible way.

Comment: try this-> <form action="index.php" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

Why you include login.php like  `<include'login.php'/>`?

it should be `<?php include 'login.php'; ?>`

And form should have action set to login.php or index.php  if you're checking if values are set on index.php

Comment: I see. When I add action="index.php" I get url /index.php/index.php

Comment: try correct absolute or relative path... you're not sending values with no action to nowhere. I would send values to login.php and in that file i would check if username and pass has correct values > if they do i would set login in session to true and then redirect with header to gallery.php